# Customize width for TextBox Jquery-1.10.min,js

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery-1.10.min.js and jquery-mobile-1.4.0.min.js and trying to customize the width for a textbox . i can notice slight changes if applied though styling (css) or by HTML markups but still jquery css is overruling it and size of the text box is not changing, it remains the same ,100%.
What could be the fix for it . Following is the code snippet.

```
  <script>
 .mystyle1
        {  .ui-input-text
        { width: 85px; display: inline-block; }}
        }        
        #box
        {
            width:20px;
        }
 </script> 
 <input id="box" type="text" class="mystyle" value="0" data-mini="true" />
```

Comment: where is jquery its simple style

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't call yourself a web developer (developer all around) unless you learn to debug your own code. In this case you need to learn to use browser developer tools so you can see real **HTML** structure.

This is how **INPUT** type text starts:

```
<input id="box" type="text" class="mystyle" value="0" data-mini="true" />
```

And this is how it looks after jQuery Mobile redesign it:

```
<div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-mini ui-shadow-inset">
    <input type="text" data-mini="true" value="0" class="mystyle" id="box"/>
</div>
```

As you can see you need to modify **INPUT** element parent object if you want to change INPUT width or placement.

## Solution

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vds2U/81/

#### HTML:

```
<span class="box-holder">
    <input id="box" type="text" class="mystyle" value="0" data-mini="true" />                    
</span>
```

#### CSS:

```
.box-holder .ui-input-text {
    width: 50px;
}
```

I have wrapped **INPUT** element with parent **SPAN** element, with it we can change inner structure using CSS. Other solution is using jQuery and accessing INPUT parent.

Comment: Thanks , But i checked the devolper options and was trying to add the width by overwriting over the  various classes which were there in the parent div as well , but was facing issues in that , thats why i quoted the query. Thanks